# Create new variable based on groupby in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below:

**I/P:**

```
id       day  start location    value   match
4413869 16080   360 5000    2   1
4413869 16080   360 5000    3   1
4413869 16080   360 5000    5   1
4413869 16080   360 5000    16  1
4413869 16080   360 5015    1   1
4413869 16080   361 -1      1   0
4413869 16080   361 -1      2   0
4413869 16080   361 -1      3   0
4413869 16080   361 -1      5   0
4413869 16080   361 -1      16  0
4413869 16080   362 -1      1   0
4413869 16080   362 -1      2   0
4413869 16080   362 -1      3   0
4413869 16080   362 -1      5   0
4413869 16080   362 -1     16   0
4413869 16080   363 -1     1    0
4413869 16080   363 -1     2    0
4413869 16080   363 -1     3    0
4413869 16080   363 -1     5    0
4413869 16080   363 -1     16   0
4413869 16080   364 -1     1    0
4413869 16080   364 -1     2    0
4413869 16080   364 -1     3    0
4413869 16080   364 -1     5    0
4413869 16080   364 -1     16   0
```

I need to do the following to get my O/P:

1. loop through combination (group) of id+day+start+location
2. if the location is in the top/first of the group then new_var = 0
3. if match is 1 in that group (starting from first) then new_var = new_var+1
4. this increment should continue until last location of that group.
5. write the last record of the group to the output.

**O/P:**

```
id       day  start loc     value match new_var
4413869 16080   360 5000    16      1   4
4413869 16080   360 5015    1       1   1
4413869 16080   361 -1      16      0   0
4413869 16080   362 -1      16      0   0
4413869 16080   363 -1      16      0   0
4413869 16080   364 -1      16      0   0
```

I know that I can use group by function,but not able think of how to iterate and increment in technical way.

Can anyone guide me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cumsum` over `match` in your `groupby`

```
df['new_var'] = df.groupby(['id', 'day', 'start', 'location']).match.cumsum()
df.head()
```

[image]

then use `last` in another `groupby`

```
df.groupby(['id', 'day', 'start', 'location'], as_index=False).last()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks piRsquared.Seems to be working fine.I will work on large dataset and let you know if there are any issues.